# How do I shorten the y-axis when using axis equal?

Tags: tikz-pgf, axis

How can I get the y-axis to be the same size as the x-axis at the negative side?

```
\documentclass[border={0.2cm 0.2cm 0.2cm 0.2cm}]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots,tikz}
\usepackage[c]{esvect}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usetikzlibrary{angles}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        % let both axes use the same layers
        \pgfplotsset{set layers}        
        \begin{axis}[
            axis line style = thick,    
            axis equal,                             
            axis x line=center,
            axis y line=center,
            %y axis line style={opacity=0},     
            %xlabel={$x$},
            %ylabel={$y$},
            xtick=\empty,
            ytick=\empty,
            xmin=-0.2,xmax=2.5,ymin=0,ymax=1, 
            every inner x axis line/.append style={-triangle 45},
            every inner y axis line/.append style={-triangle 45},
            yticklabel style = {font=\tiny,xshift=0.5ex},
            xticklabel style = {font=\tiny,yshift=0.5ex},
            %ticks=none,            
            ]       
            
            \draw [line width=1pt,-latex] (0,0) -- (35:2.5) node [midway, above left, scale=0.7,xshift=3.5ex, yshift=2.5ex] {$\boldmath{\vv{b}}$};
            
            
            \draw [line width=1pt,-latex,red] (0,0) -- (2.047880111,0) node [midway, above, scale=0.7,xshift=2.5ex] {$\boldmath{\vv{a}}$};
            
            
            \draw [line width=1pt,-latex, blue] (0,0) -- (35:1) node [midway, above left, scale=0.7] {$\boldmath{\vv{e}}$};
        
            \coordinate (A) at (35:1);
            \coordinate (B) at (0,0);
            \coordinate (C) at (1,0);
            \pic [draw, ->, angle radius=0.6cm, angle eccentricity=1.5] 
            {angle = C--B--A};
        
            \draw (0.42,0.13) node [scale=0.7] {\textbf{\textit{v}}};
            
            \draw[line width=1pt, color=black,fill=black] (0,0) circle (1pt) node [below left,scale=0.7] {\textbf{\textit{O}}};
                        
        \end{axis}  

    \end{tikzpicture}
    
    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `axis equal image=true` p. 301 in the doc and `ymin=-0.2` and with the Tom's comment `ymax=1.5`

Remark: In my opinion it is better to use `\scriptsize` instead of `\scale{0.7}` for the text and `\scriptstyle` for the math.

```
\tikz{%
        \node  [scale=0.7] at(0,0) {$\boldmath{\vv{b}}$};
        \node at (0.2,0) {$\scriptstyle\boldmath{\vv{b}}$};
        \node  [scale=0.7] at(0.4,0) {\textbf{\textit{O}}};
        \node at (0.6,0) {\scriptsize\textbf{\textit{O}}};
    }
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[border={0.2cm 0.2cm 0.2cm 0.2cm}]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}%<-- tikz is loaded by pgfplots
\usepackage[c]{esvect}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, angles}

\begin{document}  
    
\begin{tikzpicture}
    % let both axes use the same layers
    \pgfplotsset{set layers}        
    \begin{axis}[
        axis line style = thick,    
        % axis equal,
        axis equal image=true,%<-- this line                             
        axis x line=center,
        axis y line=center,
        %y axis line style={opacity=0},     
        %xlabel={$x$},
        %ylabel={$y$},
        xtick=\empty,
        ytick=\empty,
        xmin=-0.2,xmax=2.5,ymin=-0.2,ymax=1.5,%<-- this line
        every inner x axis line/.append style={-triangle 45},
        every inner y axis line/.append style={-triangle 45},
        yticklabel style = {font=\tiny,xshift=0.5ex},
        xticklabel style = {font=\tiny,yshift=0.5ex},
        %ticks=none,            
        ]  
            % \draw (0,0) circle [radius=0.2];         
            \draw [line width=1pt,-latex] (0,0) -- (35:2.5) node [midway, above left, scale=0.7,xshift=3.5ex, yshift=2.5ex] {$\boldmath{\vv{b}}$};
            
            
            \draw [line width=1pt,-latex,red] (0,0) -- (2.047880111,0) node [midway, above, scale=0.7,xshift=2.5ex] {$\boldmath{\vv{a}}$};
            
            
            \draw [line width=1pt,-latex, blue] (0,0) -- (35:1) node [midway, above left, scale=0.7] {$\boldmath{\vv{e}}$};
        
            \coordinate (A) at (35:1);
            \coordinate (B) at (0,0);
            \coordinate (C) at (1,0);
            \pic [draw, ->, angle radius=0.6cm, angle eccentricity=1.5] 
            {angle = C--B--A};
        
            \draw (0.42,0.13) node [scale=0.7] {\textbf{\textit{v}}};
            
            \draw[line width=1pt, color=black,fill=black] (0,0) circle (1pt) node [below left,scale=0.7] {\textbf{\textit{O}}};
                
        \end{axis}  
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \tikz{%
        \node  [scale=0.7] at(0,0) {$\boldmath{\vv{b}}$};
        \node at (0.2,0) {$\scriptstyle\boldmath{\vv{b}}$};
        \node  [scale=0.7] at(0.4,0) {\textbf{\textit{O}}};
        \node at (0.6,0) {\scriptsize\textbf{\textit{O}}};
    }
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Better to set larger ymax as well, cause the slant arrow have been cut off.

Comment: @Tom In fact, I hadn't seen it.